# Bash prompt line wrapping issue

Tags: macos, bash, command-prompt, ps1

Newbie question, I recently changed my PS1 into this:

```
RESET="\[\017\]"
NORMAL="\[\033[0m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"

export PS1="\[$RESET\]\u@\h:\[$CYAN\]\w\[$YELLOW\]\$(__git_ps1)\[$NORMAL\] \$ "
```

But now I get a line wrapping error. I created a gif to explain the problem:

[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: @What does your `__git_ps1` function do? Can you show us a code?

Comment: @konsolebox It's a shell script to display current branch if current directory is a git project. Code here: https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

Comment: +1 because I enjoy the gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're double-quoting your escape codes with [ and ]. Try this one:

```
export PS1="$RESET\u@\h:$CYAN\w$YELLOW\$(__git_ps1)$NORMAL \$ "
```

Answer (score 2):

The wrapping error occurs whenever a non-printing character is not escaped (such as the escape codes that change the prompt color). It also occurs when the locale is set to something that does not understand unicode characters and the prompt includes them. An example would be non-breaking spaces. When the locale is "C" and there are unicode characters in the prompt, the shell thinks more characters are being printed than truly are, and the prompt wraps around prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

`shopt -s checkwinsize` this should fix your problem.
This will set the variable `checkwinsize on`. This is set by default in /etc/bashrc however since you're using your custom .bashrc file you can put this code in there or in your .bashrc file load the /etc/bashrc by adding `. /etc/bashrc` at the top of your .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

A relative recent re-occurrence of this issue was released as part of https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ee1af8cb8b97385fc4e603bc024d877def5adb4#r139625087

I've got a PR in! Hopefully it'll get through.

But if you look for the new version of `git-prompt.sh` on your machine, in that, look got `\001` and `\002`. It is missing the escaping of the `\`. So double them up to `\\001` and `\\002`. It looks like something evaluates `\001` into `0b1`/`0x01` and `\002` into `0b10`/`0x02`.

These are observable if you `echo $PS1 | hexdump -C`.

Not sure how relevant this is, but it was changed and others have commented it as being bad. I couldn't find a PR so I made one.